page structure gets distored after publishing in wordpress
I had a website hosted on Godaddy where I got some ISP issues with them so I migrated hosting to VPS now the forms and images are not displaying properly but when I go to editor it show correctly but on the website its not displaying properly as per images below



its showing as per the setting. Like in the dashboard if you take a closer look then you have 2 columns and when you publish the changes then the site also shows in 2 columns.

pay attention to the text fields in published version they are shorter and even the background color is also missing, but in editor they all are equal and background of form is also colored, in the same way in other pages I have different issues like missing images and same textboxes in different size mixedup layouts etc

load the site in incognito mode, also check it in other browsers, as mostly the chrome extension cause issues with the site result. also double check thing in Inspect Element as you can check where css/js/ any files are missing or is there and other issue in the console.
